# Using the MATE clock applet without a password

Tags: linux-mint, mate-desktop, timezone

This is just a minor annoyance, but I'd love to fix it.

I'm running Mint 17 with MATE 1.8.1. The clock applet on my panel knows my location, and displays the weather. Sometimes I like to look at other places where I've lived, and see how they're doing. If I change to a different city in the same timezone, all works fine. But it demands the superuser password if I want to change to a different timezone. (Which is long and annoying to type.)

Is there any way to set things up so that the clock applet is allowed to change the timezone, without screwing up my security settings too badly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Mate you can set additional timezones. Go to `Clock Preferences -> Locations -> Add`. Once finished, click the clock to change the current timezone. The weather report should get updated accordingly. ([source](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/timezone.html))

Alternatively, you can try a different weather applet. [`indicator-weather` from `ppa:weather-indicator-team/ppa`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WeatherIndicator) seems to have the feature you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but you misunderstand the question.

I have 5 locations all added to the applet. So long as I just shuffle among the 3 on the US Pacific coast, it's fine. But once I select one (within the main body of the applet--beneath the map) in a different timezone, it wants the superuser password. What I want is for the clock applet to be able to change my computer's timezone, without needing a password.